# Excel: Add number to upper right corner of box of merged cells

Tags: excel, text, formatting

I have an excel form which displays a six generation family pedigree chart.  Each box for a person's data is merged together from 3 columns and 7 rows.  4 lines of text fit into each box, the 1st line is name, the 2nd birth date and place, the 3rd marriage date and place and the 4th death date and place.

The rightmost two columns are the triple great grandparents of the root person and sometimes a 2nd chart is needed to show their ancestors.  The 2nd chart tile is Chart mm-nn where mm is the chart number where the person appears as a GGG grandparent and nn is their number in that chart.

How can I put a number in the upper right corner of these boxes in my chart?

I thought of appending the number to the person's name and flush it right.  If possible, it must be with some exotic format string.  But each box has 4 text lines and the flush right formatting needs only apply to the 1st.

Perhaps make the numbers as little graphics and overlay them?  Chop up the base cells even smaller and merge them into 4 separate lines with the 1st line shorter than the others with a small number box at the end of it?

Ideas?

Jim

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, James. It seems to me that you have read the [tour page of this website](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and thus know that this website is not about discussing opinions or brainstorming ideas. We don't even encourage chit-chat. Just questions and answers. Of course that means also that the questions should be very precise to allow for an immediate answer. Yet, as the question stands (right now) it seems much too broad for this site. So, please try to be more specific and possibly amend screenshots to your post of what you have and what your desired outcome should be.

Comment: Sorry for the prolixity.  I have a merged cells box in Excel which will contain four lines of wrapped text.  The four lines are separated by <alt><cr>.  On the first line I would like to have two strings of text, one left justified and the other right.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: no, that's not possible. This is Excel not MS Word. Hence, you can set any given cell only to be `left-justified` or `right-justified`. You cannot have both for one cell.

Yet, maybe any of the following work-around might be of help in your case. Of course, I can't be sure since you haven't provided any screenshots of the desired out-come (like a mock-up). But here we go:

This is where you are coming from. A merged box of three columns by seven rows containing four lines of text.

[image]

(1) One solution might be to have three different merged areas. The following example consists of three merged areas. The first two rows and the first two columns make up the name. The last column on the first two rows is merged to contain the number and the rest is one merged box again containing the dates and the places.

[image]

<sub>Note, that you can only see the difference to the original since I selected in this example the top right merged area (consisting of the number only). Otherwise, there wouldn't be any (visually apparent) difference.</sub>

(2) Another solution could be to manually insert as many spaces after the name as necessary to make it seem as if it were `right-justified`. The problem here is (of course) that this changes with the font, the font-size, if the font is bold (or italic) or not, and also the current zoom-factor for the sheet. Hence, this solution would soon wear you out as you would have to manually adjust all the cells constantly. I just wanted to point out this solution for the sake of completeness.

[image]

(3) The following solution consists of a `text box` shape on top of the cell. So, basically I am leaving your original cell (consisting of three columns and seven rows) as is and simply put a shape on top of that cell. The following screenshot shows the result in the top part and the text box being selected in the bottom part (so you can see how this one comes together).

[image]

(4) The following work-around is probably the solution you've been looking for and you want to go with. This one is moving away from the cells on the sheet and relies **only** on text-boxes which are shown on top of the sheet (and thus on top of the cells). Here you can "merge" several text boxes into a group. The group will move and size as a whole. At the same time this group consists of several text boxes and as such may consist of `left-justified` text boxes and `right-justified` text boxes as you can see in the screencast below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Ralph, what a thorough answer!  As it happens, I thought of your first suggestion and implemented it.  I set all my columns to width 2 and rows to height 4.5, then merged 6 columns and 2 rows for the top line and 7 columns and 2 rows each for the next three lines.  This gives each line of text its own cell.  Here is a screenshot of my completed page...sorry, can't seem to get a screenshot into this comment.  I like the last solution of all text boxes, too.  Thanks very much for your time and suggestions.

Comment: I did up vote your answer, but it said my vote would be registered but, as a newbie, not show up in the vote counter.  I have just now clicked the check mark to indicate my acceptance of the answer.